# Why is this script creating a duplicate file and adding `-e` to the end?

Tags: sed, terminal, bash

I will firstly say that I'm not sure if this should be here or SuperUser, so let me know if I need to remove.

I'm making a function inside `~./bash_profile` to help me when I'm starting up new Laravel projects. Here's the script:

```
function bootlaravel {
PROJECT=$1
echo "Magically creating a new Laravel project: $PROJECT..."
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
laravel new $PROJECT
cd $PROJECT
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Install Laravel"
sed -i -e "s/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE=$PROJECT/g" .env
sed -i -e "s/DB_USERNAME=homestead/DB_USERNAME=root/g" .env
sed -i -e "s/DB_PASSWORD=secret/DB_PASSWORD=/g" .env
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot -e "create database $PROJECT DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci"
open "http://$PROJECT.dev"
pstorm .
echo "Project: $PROJECT has been created. Have fun!"
}
```

Usage is something like `bootlaravel LaravelProjectName`

Where the `sed` commands are being used to modify the `.env` file, it's actually creating a `.env-e` file as a sibling to the existing `.env` file. I can't actually understand why it's doing this. It changes the words as required fine though.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try `sed -ie` instead of `sed -i -e`? Since `-i` modifies the extension and `-e` is getting added I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: @CormacO'Brien nearly, now it says `.enve` haha

Comment: Do you want backups? That's the idea with `sed -i`, and the flag requires an extension of non-zero length. If not, just drop the `-i` flag, otherwise give it an extension like `.bak`.

Comment: I'll try that, backup isn't required as Laravel ships with a `.env-example` file I can copy things from if something was to go wrong

Comment: @CormacO'Brien if I drop the `-i` it doesn't do the replace

Comment: If you leave the `-i` option out you have to provide an output file. `-i` indicates that the file should be edited in-place, which requires a backup. @Kusalananda's answer seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally advise against using `sed -i` at all, especially when trying things out or moving scripts between platforms.  The BSD `sed` (on OS X for example) *requires* an argument to `-i`, and this is probably also why you get an `-e` suffix on your file (and *definitely* why `-ie` gives you an `e` suffix, even with GNU `sed`).

Your three invocations of `sed` may be combined:

```
sed -e 's/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE='"$PROJECT"'/g' \
    -e 's/DB_USERNAME=homestead/DB_USERNAME=root/g' \
    -e 's/DB_PASSWORD=secret/DB_PASSWORD=/g' .env >.env-new &&
mv -f .env-new .env
```

In my mind, using a temporary file is a small price to pay for portability and robustness.

Additionally, quote all user-supplied strings. In your case, `$PROJECT` and `$1`, you have a nice SQL injection possibility there otherwise, for example.

If I got the SQL quoting right, this would be the modified shell function:

```
function bootlaravel {
    local project="$1"

    echo "Magically creating a new Laravel project: $project..."

    cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs || return 1    
    laravel new "$project"
    cd "$project" || return 1

    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m "Install Laravel"

    sed -e 's/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE='"$project"'/g' \
        -e 's/DB_USERNAME=homestead/DB_USERNAME=root/g' \
        -e 's/DB_PASSWORD=secret/DB_PASSWORD=/g' .env >.env-new &&
    mv -f .env-new .env

    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql \
        --host=localhost -uroot -proot <<SQL_END
CREATE DATABASE \`$project\`
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci
SQL_END

    open "http://$project.dev"
    pstorm .

    echo "Project: $project has been created. Have fun!"
}
```

This also uses a lowercase `$project` (uppercase generally used for environment variables), and will return a non-zero status if any of the `cd` fails. I also declare `project` as a local variable in the function as to not pollute the calling shell with new shell variables. The empty lines etc. are mostly for readability.

Comment: Just heading home, will try this as soon as I'm back

Comment: To avoid any surprises, always enclose scripts with single quotes, not double, and just break out when necessary, e.g. `'s/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE='"$PROJECT"'/g'` and always use `&&` between `cmd file > tmp` and `mv tmp file` so you don't zap your original file on a failure.

Comment: @EdMorton Ye gods! Sorry! Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Is there a reason for the bash-only function declaration syntax? At a quick glance, this answer's code would be POSIX sh compliant if it were `bootlaravel() {` instead of `function bootlaravel {`.

Comment: ...if you were inclined to introduce some minor incompatibilities ("minor" because this is an extension to the POSIX sh standard than even ash/dash/etc. implement), I might make it `local project="$1"`, to avoid overwriting a variable defined outside the function which might happen to have the same name.

Comment: ...right now, the `unset project` at the end means you're actually *clearing* any preexisting global by that name. Much, much better to declare it a local.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I appreciate the input. This seems to be `bash` (from the mentioning of `.bash_profile`) so declaring `project` as local would definitely be appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I usually use `typeset` though, as `local` isn't understood by my favourite shell, `ksh93`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `declare` is not available in `ksh93`. `typeset` is the `ksh` Swiss army knife of that sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll try to make a habit of preferring it when writing code intended to work across bash and ksh.

Comment: I got this `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''CRM2'
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1` looking into it now

Comment: Ah, taking the quotes out here `CREATE DATABASE '$project'` worked. So now it's just `CREATE DATABASE $project` - seems to work fine now :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes That leaves `$project` unquoted. Use backticks instead (escaped to protect them from the shell). I can never get SQL quoting rules right on the first try... I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you :) This works really well, nicely done